How to make a custom response for ValidationAttribute in C#?
I am working on a custom ValidationAttribute, something along the lines of this:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class CustomRegexValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!Regex.Match((string)value, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+$").Success)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Invalid Format");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}

The response looks something like this:
{
    "errors": {
        "variableName": [
            "Invalid Format"
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-f8c2d18438cfa0cea6967f46a5bf8ba1-0f3447a15a1dbc-00"
}

However, I need to access the passed string dynamically from our front-end, and the nested format will not work. Is it possible to create a custom response for this?

Hi @Ben F,what is your target framework?

The response you're seeing is a standards-based response using the ProblemDetails class.  It's not a super great idea to start changing this stuff on the server side.  It's best to fix your client.
But if you must, you're probably going to have to let ASP.NET render the output as is, and then use an ActionFilter to manipulate it into what you want.
The ActionFilter allows you to take a potential HTTP output stream and change it into something else before the server transmits it.  I have used this approach to allow global macros in HTML, or insert global scripts.  You can do the same with JSON.  You have to check that you're manipulating responses with the correct Content-Type, and then make sure you're not messing up JSON that has nothing to do with these error responses.
See more here.
https://blog.rsuter.com/post-process-the-html-output-of-an-action-in-asp-net-mvc/

The ASP.NET validation system's attribute-centric model comes with some built-in limitations, so you may consider implementing validation in a way that gives you better control over the output. From a computer science perspective, validation looks like a solved problem, but unfortunately, the way that ASP.NET validation works is based on predicates rather than applicative functors.
The problem with using predicates is that they naturally lead to Boolean logic, which has a tendency to short-circuit: For example, when evaluating Boolean conjunction ('and'), as soon as you encounter a false value, there's no reason to keep evaluating more input. In the context of input validation, such behaviour is rarely desirable, because you'd want to enumerate to a client application as many errors as possible. As my linked article ASP.NET validation revisited demonstrates, ASP.NET validation makes an attempt at collecting problems, but sometimes fails to do so.
You may consider my article An applicative reservation validation example in C# as a starting point if you're curious about a more disciplined approach to validation in .NET, but if you're new to this topic, be sure to follow the links and set aside some time to read the fundamentals first.

I need to access the passed string dynamically from our front-end

You may have good reasons for this, but if you're planning on passing the string on to the user, you may want to reconsider that position. Exception messages, at least, are for other developers, not for end users.
